# Encrypt with BouncyCastle PGP and decrypt with Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

I am trying to encrypt a string using Bouncy Castle PGP Java apis(1.57), Base64 encode the encrypted string and then decrypt using Postgres (9.4.4) pg_pub_decrypt but it is failing with error “Wrong Key”. Just wanted to know if this is doable or pg_pub_decrypt only works with encrypted strings from pg_pub_encrypt?

Comment: Interesting thread about those functions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CACjxUsMwjey7tCm1aKoMfHXLSUTuoLWHeir_7%3DHaNQa26maqFw%40mail.gmail.com#CACjxUsMwjey7tCm1aKoMfHXLSUTuoLWHeir_7=HaNQa26maqFw@mail.gmail.com)

Comment: Thanks Maarten Bodewes. Do you know how to add the marker in the encrypted message so it can be decrypted by pg_pub_decrypt?

Comment: No, unfortunately not: I would have to study the otherwise undocumented format for that